# Non-consumable IAP

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval, iphone-developer-program

For an iOS game application that has in-app purchases which are considered to be non-consumable (buy once and permanently unlock) when logging onto account A from a different device, a user has the option to restore items purchased, but creating a new game account or multiple accounts what should/shouldn’t be allowed with restoring and what is recommended in this scenario from a dev point of view?

Answer (score 0):

The purchase and restoring is done by Apple and you can't influence that. If the user click restore, you don't have to do any check yourself. You make a call so Apple checks if this user has already done the purchase. It means that a user on a new phone can restore using its account, but a user making a new account can't restore. To you it doesn't matter. You show the restore button anyway and let Apple's API tell you what must be restored.

[This links](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/offering_completing_and_restoring_in-app_purchases?language=objc) contains the Apple guideline for restoring IAP.

Comment: The link provided in this answer now forwards to the home page of the StoreKit documentation.

Comment: I edited the link. Note that you could have googled it and suggested the edit yourself